# Unsure as to how to have a bot send a message when a member joins a Discord Server

Tags: python, discord.py

First off, I tried googling this and could never really find an answer so here I am on stackoverflow. So, I'm trying to add a greeting effect to my discord bot but can't seem to be able to send a message. I know the bot isn't sending the message because "message" is not defined when using message.channel.send but I don't know the correct way to do so.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 20, in on_member_join
NameError: name 'message' is not defined`)
```

```py
import discord


bot = discord.Client() 

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in')
    print("Username: %s" % (bot.user.name))
    print("Userid: %s" % (bot.user.id))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined the server')
    await message.channel.send('{member} has joined the server'.format(message))

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left the server')
    await message.channel.send('{member} has left the server'.format(message))

bot.run(Token)
```

Comment: What channel do you want to send the message to?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh How do you get a bot to send a channel name (ex. #test with the actual "link" to that channel) with the id?
Edit: I also need to check what channel a message was sent in. I'm trying to have the bot check if a string, say "foo" is in a message and also in any channel except #bar. Also sorry for the requests

Comment: @DartRuffian, Assuming you're trying to mention a channel, if you look at my answer from earlier, you can do `channel.mention` which will send a clickable channel name that redirects to that channel.

Comment: @Jawad Yea I acutally did figure it out (I wasn't using a "#" before id channel id) not long after I posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) to get your #welcome channel, assign it to a variable, then send the welcome message.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(730064641857683581)  # Replace with your Welcome channel ID
    await channel.send(f"{member} has joined the server")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. `message.channel.send` will never work if `message` is not defined, which it's not. `message` is a parameter of some `discord.py` functions, but not `on_member_join` or `on_member_remove`, since these don't happen in a specific channel. You will have to pre-specify which channel to send the message to.

Comment: I knew it would never work because `message` would not be defined; however I did not know and couldn't find the proper way to define it.